# Can't download pgadmin4 for Fedora

Tags: installation, fedora, yum, pgadmin-4, dnf

The following error appears when trying to download pgadmin4 from a Fedora 37 System.

```
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'pgAdmin4':
  - Status code: 404 for https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/yum/fedora/fedora-37-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'pgAdmin4': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried

...

Ignoring repositories: pgAdmin4
No match for argument: pgadmin4-desktop
Error: Unable to find a match: pgadmin4-desktop
```

I'm following the official documentation displayed here: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-rpm/

I have tried: sudo dnf clean all; sudo dnf update; sudo rm -r /var/cache/dnf;
(I know that the official docs includes yum in its examples. It's what I have been using, but I have also tried dnf).

Is it a my problem or a problem with the downloads page? Is there something I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing you can do - only downgrade to fedora36 or take rpm from repo of fedora 36, edit it to link to fedora 36 for fedora 37 and try to install it manually(generally bad idea)

The reason this happens is they do not have a repo for fedora 37 yet

Upd: tested it myself - looks like they have nop fedora 37 repo for a reason - pgadmin server from 36 repo wont start on 37 core version